# Create thumbnail image and post two images

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I need to upload one image and create thumbnail image on client side and upload these two images in different folders in asp classic.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file you can use Free ASP Upload, available here

http://www.freeaspupload.net/

Or you can buy and install a third party component on your server such as Persits ASP Upload

http://www.aspupload.com/

If you want ASP to do the image resizing you'll need a third party component for that too, such as aspjpeg

http://www.aspjpeg.com/